# Can I manage Yahoo! Groups on behalf of many people?

Tags: yahoo-groups

I want to build a website which will allow people to migrate from a Yahoo! Groups, but interaction with the group must still be possible.  To this end I want to have people's interaction with the group done by the website. The group emails have the "reply to" address as the user's personal email address, not the group address.

So the website will need to post users' entries to the group with a unique "reply to" address and then receive replies to that address so that they can marked as replies to the users that sent them.

Is there a way that I can do this?

I considered having a single user on the group for the website and then modifying the reply to address so that it was something like `website+<userid>@website.email.com` but I'm not sure if the groups can be configured to allow this as a reply to address.  Or perhaps to allow all posts from a particular subdomain so that the reply could be `<userid>@website.email.com` and all posts from *@website.email.com are allowed.

Can I create users of the group programmatically to support this?